# Erro no import de CSV com Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

tenho um arquivo ".csv" padrão que disponibilizo pro cliente fazer o download, preencher e após completar o preenchimento, fazer o import pra plataforma.

Acontece que o CSV quando aberto por excel, cria uma linha vazia no fim do arquivo, que só consegui ver abrindo em um editor de textos simples, após fechar e salvar no excel.

Quando faço o import na plataforma, ele quebra e me retorna erro. Vou lá no arquivo de novo através do editor de textos, excluo a última linha e pronto. Funciona normal.

Quero tentar fazer com que meu código desconsidere qualquer espaço vazio após o último caracter do csv, não sendo "vírgula". Ou validando se existe linhas em branco e apenas desconsiderá-las.

Segue código: **Uso createUser pq implementei o componente pra validar se já existe usuário com a matricula enviada**

```
onEventSubmit(userList: User[]) {
this.modalService.close(this.importFormId);
if (userList) {
  userList.forEach(userInstance => {
    this.userService.createUser(userInstance).subscribe(
      _ => {
        this.refreshDatatable(),
          this.alertService.success('Cadastro bem sucedido');
      },
      error => {
        this.alertService.error(
          'Verifique seu CSV',
          'Erro ao cadastrar usuário'
        );
      }
    );
  });
}
```